# Issue with Camera shortcut

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

I am trying to use the *Camera*. I am aware that if you find a nice position you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Num:0</kbd> but this does not work for me.

---

I am using a *MacBook* if that changed anything.

Comment: You can also use fly navigation. Check out the key bindings, you can search them in Edit>>Preferences>>Keymap.

Comment: Try using Cmd + Alt + 0 instead of Ctrl+ Alt + 0

Comment: I tried that but still does not work.